# sklearn Logistic Regression "ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2."

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I attempt to solve [this problem 6 in this notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_deep_learning/1_notmnist.ipynb). The question is to train a simple model on this data using 50, 100, 1000 and 5000 training samples by using the LogisticRegression model from `sklearn.linear_model`.

```
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(train_dataset,train_labels)
```

This is the code i trying to do and it give me the error.

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Any idea?

Comment: The github link in this question is now dead.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

scikit-learn expects 2d num arrays for the training dataset for a [fit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit) function. The dataset you are passing in is a 3d array you need to reshape the array into a 2d.

```
nsamples, nx, ny = train_dataset.shape
d2_train_dataset = train_dataset.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how ndarray.reshape can magically transform 3D data to 2D without losing the information represented by the original vectors?

Comment: First dimension is maintained and the other two dimensions are flattened (so 28x28 becomes 784). The fit algorithm will next consider the first 784 features part of sample number one and the next 784 features part of sample two and so on.

Comment: I have my X data separate from y labels. How can I flatten the X train dataset using this answer?  Y labels are a 5k array.   X_train is a 5k x 1024 x 1024

Comment: You are correct, but how did you get that information? The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit) clearly says  `Parameters: X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape (n_samples, n_features)`

Comment: So if I reshaped my data this way, fitted it and predicted my y. The shape of my y is now (nsamples, 1). But what I need y to be is (nx,ny) because I need a label for each pixel. What should I do in this case?

Comment: This is wrong answer. nrgb is missing as the 4th parameter.

Answer (score 13):

In LSTM, GRU, and TCN layers, the return_sequence  in last layer before  Dence Layer must set False .
It is one of conditions  that you encounter to this error message .

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is stumbling onto this question from using LSTM or any RNN for two or more time series, this might be a solution.

However, to those who want error between two different values predicted, if for example you're trying to predict two completely different time series, then you can do the following:

```python
from sklearn import mean_squared_error 
# Any sklearn function that takes 2D data only
# 3D data
real = np.array([
    [
        [1,60],
        [2,70],
        [3,80]
    ],
    [
        [2,70],
        [3,80],
        [4,90]
    ]
]) 

pred = np.array([
    [
        [1.1,62.1],
        [2.1,72.1],
        [3.1,82.1]
    ],
    [
        [2.1,72.1],
        [3.1,82.1],
        [4.1,92.1]
    ]
])

# Error/Some Metric on Feature 1:
print(mean_squared_error(real[:,:,0], pred[:,:,0]) # 0.1000

# Error/Some Metric on Feature 2:
print(mean_squared_error(real[:,:,1], pred[:,:,1]) # 2.0000
```

[Additional Info from the numpy indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Answer (score 3):

You probably have the last "lstm" layer in your model using "return_sequences=True".
Change this to false to not return the output for further lstm models.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar Error by solving an image classification problem. We have a 3D matrix: the first dimension is the total number of images, can be replaced by "-1", the second dimension is the product of the height and the width of the picture, the third dimension is equal to three, since the RGB image has three channels (red, green blue). If we don't want to lose information about the color of the image, then we use x_train.reshape(-1, nx*ny*3). If the color can be neglected and thereby reduce the size of the matrix: x_train.reshape(-1, nx*ny*1)