# sklearn KNeighborsClassifier "ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2."

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I am trying to train a simple model with sklearn kneighborsclassifier on wine quality data. This is my code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataframe = pd.read_csv("winequality-white.csv")
dataframe = dataframe.drop(["fixed acidity", "pH", "sulphates"], axis=1)

test = dataframe[110:128]
train = dataframe[15:40]

Y = train["quality"]
X = train.drop(["quality"], axis=1)


#print(X)
#print(Y)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(X, Y)
testvals = np.array(test.loc[110, :])
testvals = testvals.reshape(1, -1)
print(knn.predict([[testvals]]))
```

I get the error "ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2."

I'm fairly certain it has something to do with the shape of my array and I have tried to reshape it, but had no luck. What should I do?

Comment: What line is raising the ValueError?

Comment: It was the very last line, because my testvals array was a 4-D array. The problem was solved when I popped the target off test and just passed one entry of the array through predict, I didn't need to reshape it at all. As shown by @Tgsmith61591

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following (reproducible) example setup:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> test = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=np.random.rand(120, 4))
>>> testvals = np.array(test.loc[110, :])
```

The way you're reshaping your vector when you pass it to the predict function is creating an array with more than the expected 2 dims (i.e., a multidimensional array). Here's the output of your reshape that you're passing into the predict function:

```
>>> [[testvals.reshape((-1, 1))]]
[[array([[ 0.25174728],
       [ 0.24603664],
       [ 0.01781963],
       [ 0.49317648]])]]
```

We can show this produces a 4-d array:

```
>>> np.asarray([[testvals.reshape((-1, 1))]]).ndim
4
```

Sklearn expects a 2d array. Here's how you can fix it... If you want to predict the entire matrix, just run:

```
knn.predict(test)
```

If you just want to predict for one sample, you could do:

```
knn.predict([test.loc[110].tolist()])
```

By the way, it's worth mentioning you have still not popped the target off of `test`, so the number of features won't match until you do:

```
y_test = test.pop('quality')
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972142/sklearn-logistic-regression-valueerror-found-array-with-dim-3-estimator-expec?rq=1)