# Python - window size for machine learning model

Tags: python-3.x, keras, logistic-regression, windowing

i am working on a python task using logistic regression classifier and i am trying to set w window size = 2 for the input data before the fitting step. here is what i have tried

```
from itertools import islice
def window(seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result

x_train = list(window(x_train))
y_train = list(window(y_train))
x_test = list(window(x_test))
y_test = list(window(y_test))
seed = 42
##LogisticRegressionCV Classifier
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred1=lr.predict(x_test)

kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(lr, x_train, y_train, cv=kfold)
```

here is i have used a function to apply a window size = 2 but in the fitting step the following error appears because the shape of the dataset after the windowing is edited for example like that ((1150731, 2, 3)) instead of (1150731,3)

> ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sklearn Logistic Regression "ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972142/sklearn-logistic-regression-valueerror-found-array-with-dim-3-estimator-expec)